# Robot drives near keepout zones, and stops when "incidentally" enters the keepout zone

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, nav2

**Required Info:**

- Operating System:

  - Ubuntu 22.04
- ROS2 Version:

  - Humble
- Version or commit hash:

  - apt binary

##### Steps to reproduce issue

I'm using DWBLocalPlanner on a rectangular robot.
The robot needs to go from point A to point B, and in between, the robot has to turn right to avoid keepout zones (Picture below)
[image]

This is quite identical with this issue https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3102 , I've tried adding inflatioin layer, but the problem persists.

Parameter file:

```yaml
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_link"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 4.0
    laser_max_range: 12.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 100
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.1
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.9
    z_max: 0.1
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan
    set_initial_pose: True
    initial_pose:
      x: 20.144
      y: -1.114
      z: 0.0
      yaw: 1.615

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /rover/odom
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_navigate_through_poses_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugins: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 100.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 360.0
      stateful: True
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 0.26
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics:
        [
          "Oscillation",
          "BaseObstacle",
          "GoalAlign",
          "PathAlign",
          "PathDist",
          "GoalDist",
        ]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.1
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 5
      height: 5
      resolution: 0.05
      # robot_radius: 1.0
      footprint: "[ [0.6, 0.3], [0.6, -0.3], [-0.6, -0.3], [-0.6, 0.3] ]"
      footprint_padding: 0.1
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      filters: ["keepout_filter"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
        inflation_radius: 0.4
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          obstacle_max_range: 5.0
          raytrace_max_range: 8.0
          marking: true
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      keepout_filter:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::KeepoutFilter"
        enabled: True
        filter_info_topic: "/costmap_filter_info"
        transform_tolerance: 0.1

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      # robot_radius: 1.0
      footprint: "[ [0.6, 0.3], [0.6, -0.3], [-0.6, -0.3], [-0.6, 0.3] ]"
      footprint_padding: 0.1
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      filters: ["keepout_filter"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        footprint_clearing_enabled: True
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.0
          raytrace_max_range: 8.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
        inflation_radius: 0.4
      keepout_filter:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::KeepoutFilter"
        enabled: True
        filter_info_topic: "/costmap_filter_info"
      always_send_full_costmap: True

costmap_filter_info_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    type: 0
    filter_info_topic: "/costmap_filter_info"
    mask_topic: "/keepout_filter_mask"
    base: 0.0
    multiplier: 1.0

filter_mask_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    frame_id: "map"
    topic_name: "/keepout_filter_mask"
    yaml_filename: "mask.yaml"

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: "map_1700200021.yaml"
    topic_name: "map"
    frame_id: "map"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5000
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerHybrid"
      downsample_costmap: false # whether or not to downsample the map
      downsampling_factor: 1 # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
      tolerance: 0.5 # dist-to-goal heuristic cost (distance) for valid tolerance endpoints if exact goal cannot be found.
      allow_unknown: false # allow traveling in unknown space
      max_iterations: 1000000 # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000 # Maximum number of iterations after within tolerances to continue to try to find exact solution
      max_planning_time: 5.0 # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
      motion_model_for_search: "DUBIN" # Hybrid-A* Dubin, Redds-Shepp
      angle_quantization_bins: 72 # Number of angle bins for search
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5 # The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0 # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting
      analytic_expansion_max_cost: 200.0 # The maximum single cost for any part of an analytic expansion to contain and be valid, except when necessary on approach to goal
      analytic_expansion_max_cost_override: false #  Whether or not to override the maximum cost setting if within critical distance to goal (ie probably required)
      minimum_turning_radius: 0.1 # minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
      reverse_penalty: 2.0 # Penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 0.0 # Penalty to apply if motion is changing directions (L to R), must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 1.0 # Penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 2.0 # Penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      retrospective_penalty: 0.015
      lookup_table_size: 20.0 # Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: false # Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.
      debug_visualizations: false # For Hybrid nodes: Whether to publish expansions on the /expansions topic as an array of poses (the orientation has no meaning) and the path's footprints on the /planned_footprints topic. WARNING: heavy to compute and to display, for debug only as it degrades the performance.
      use_quadratic_cost_penalty: False
      downsample_obstacle_heuristic: True
      allow_primitive_interpolation: False
      smooth_path: True # If true, does a simple and quick smoothing post-processing to the path
      footprint: "[ [0.6, 0.3], [0.6, -0.3], [-0.6, -0.3], [-0.6, 0.3] ]"

      smoother:
        max_iterations: 1000
        w_smooth: 0.3
        w_data: 0.2
        tolerance: 1.0e-10
        do_refinement: true
        refinement_num: 2

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: global_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: global_costmap/published_footprint
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      do_refinement: True
      refinement_num: 2
      max_its: 1000
      w_data: 0.2
      w_smooth: 0.3

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins:
      ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.26, 0.0, 1.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.26, 0.0, -1.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0
```

##### Expected behavior

1. The robot drive further from the keepout zones. (Though I suppose the reason of why the robot drives near the keepout zone is because it's nearer.)
2. Even though the robot "enters" the keepout zones, I want it to still drive forward instead of stopping.

##### Actual behavior

The robot generate path that is very close with the keepout zone, and eventually enters it, and get stuck there.

##### Additional information

I have tried adding inflation layor as suggested here https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3102#issuecomment-1225494691 , the robot drives furthere from the keepout zone, but somehow still managed to get stuck in the keepout zone. If I make the inflation layer bigger, the robot won't e able to move along the narrow path.

*I asked this question [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/4153) but then move the ticket here

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to have you close this ticket about the keep out "how do I get out" problem, but your follow up problem question on the other not entirely related issue in your second comment. That's what I wanted to break out into a Question to keep the the main ticket problem thread on topic.